# xamp: how I can get localhost page (with big xampp logo)

Tags: mysql, apache

I have installed XAMPP and started Apache and MySQL, but when I try to enter local host it appears that

```
----- <Welcome to XAMPP for Windows 5.6.12
You have successfully installed XAMPP on this system! Now you can start using Apache, MySQL, PHP and other components. You can find more info in the FAQs section or check the HOW-TO Guides for getting started with PHP applications.

Start the XAMPP Control Panel to check the server status.> -----
```

the XAMPP s own dashboard page.. it seems every thing is ok Apache and MySQL are running but I cant get local host page. what have to do?

Comment: ----- <Welcome to XAMPP for Windows 5.6.12
You have successfully installed XAMPP on this system! Now you can start using Apache, MySQL, PHP and other components. You can find more info in the FAQs section or check the HOW-TO Guides for getting started with PHP applications.

Start the XAMPP Control Panel to check the server status >.------  this appear (dashboard page)

Comment: Just write http://localhost/dashboard/ what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://localhost/xampp

Perphaps the http server is blocked by your local firewall?